# What's the right way to save HTML in Laravel using eloquent particularily?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, ckeditor

Do I need to use HTML::entities(Input::get('description')); in laravel to save the htmlText gotten off CKEditor. or has anyone tried it out... thanks.

The idea is to preserve the formatting and retain the text to display on another page, alternatively is there any package in packagist that one can download to strip and work on html inputs...

Please Note :: i am currently using laravel 4.2, so if there are changes in higher versions how can i implement it here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Controller File:

echo e(Input::get('description'));

Comment: thanks, something close to that..  e( ) only sanitizes the input... 
lets see if it gets the job done, thanks by the way.